# Is it wise to remove duplicate data for A/B test analysis?

Tags: python, sql

I just started my data analysis journey. I am hoping to get some guides from here. I am working on an AB test analysis, and I found some duplicate data. Should I remove them before I start?

Here is the display columns:
USER_ID | VARIANT | REVENUE

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This looks like question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)